# Get IPs for specific interface

Tags: ruby

`Socket.ip_address_list` gives the list of all IPs for all interfaces. How can I get the IPs for a specific interface?

I can't update my Ruby to anything newer than 1.9.3.

Comment: Perhaps this may help https://github.com/jeffWelling/ruby-ifconfig

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, no. It was simpler to change some behavior in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`ip_address_list` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-ip_address_list), `Socket#ip_address_list` returns local IP addresses as an array. An array has `select` and `collect` methods.

```
Socket.ip_address_list.select{|i| i.ipv4?}.collect(&:ip_address)
=> ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.13"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Ohai](https://github.com/chef/ohai) [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ohai), provided by [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), can extract ***tons*** of system information, including IP addresses for a specific interface.

First, install Ohai v7, since it's the last version compatible with 1.9

```
gem install 'ohai' --version="<8"
```

To get an idea of the data you can extract, run Ohai's command line app, `ohai`. It prints a giant JSON document to STDOUT with an expanse of data about your system.

Then, extract the network information you're looking for from your Ruby code. Assuming you wanted an array of IPv4 addresses for interface `en1`, you could select them like this:

```
require 'ohai'

# Load Ohai and query for network information
system_info = Ohai::System.new
system_info.all_plugins("network") # Run the network plugins only

# Drill down to en1 addresses
addresses = system_info['network']['interfaces']['en1']['addresses']

# Select the IPv4 addresses
ip_addresses = addresses.select {|ipaddr, attrs| attrs['family'] == 'inet' }.keys
# => ["192.168.1.115"]
```

Another way to extract the information would be to parse the information from the `ohai` command-line app:

```
require 'json'
system_info = JSON.parse(`ohai`)
system_info['network']['interfaces']['en1']['addresses'].select {|_,h| h['family'] == 'inet'}.keys
# => ["192.168.1.115"]
```

Another option is the [Sigar gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sigar):

```
# gem install sigar
require 'sigar'
sigar = Sigar.new
sigar.net_interface_config('en1').address # => "192.168.1.115"
```